# Jquery ui tabs how to hide on page load then show when nav clicked

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a pretty standard Jquery UI Tabs setup working just fine.  I even have them linkable.  Here is the code:

```
$('#tabs-set').tabs({   
        'select': function(){$(this).index($(document.location.hash));},
        'load': function(event, ui){document.location.hash = ui.panel.id;}
    });
```

What I want to do is hide all tabs instead of loading the first in the index, then if any are clicked they show.... any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's 2 options in the jQueryUI tabs that I would try:
First one I would try is not selecting a tab on initialization by setting the selected tab to -1:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ selected: -1 });
```

If that doesn't work, I'm not entirely sure what disabled would do, but I would give that one a try:

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({ disabled: true });
```

Comment: Tried adding both with no change... I am attempting to add it above the 'select' line and I am putting a comma after...

Comment: Wound up getting it to work with the first option, just had to place it after the other tabs code.

Answer (score 0):

Neither one worked for me.  I'm using a hover to select the tab.  I want to be able to hide all tabs on page load and then display the div for the tab when hovering.  I'm actually trying to use the tabs as a menu instead of as a tab control.  Perhaps this isn't possible.